# Search for specific data in a text file based on user input

Tags: python, function, file, search, io

I am new to Python and have searched for how to do this, but I can't find a solution. I have a text file full of students names, and I want to be able to enter a student ID and bring up a record of that student. I tried to put it into a function. Thanks in advance of any help.

```
search = input("Please enter a student ID: ")
file = open("Students.txt", 'r')
for i in file:
    data = i.rstrip()
    data = data.split(",")
    if(ID == data[0]):
        print("\nThe student you require is: {} {} \n".format(data[2],data[1]))
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to put into a function? All of it? How flexible should the function be? What parameters will it take? As of now, this is too broad to answer.

Comment: Being able to search for a student by their ID. def SearchStudent(): then the code.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ So the program does work by itself when I run it. However, I am having difficulty with it now being with the rest of my code and I just don't understand why.

Comment: No worries. Open a new question and explain what the problem is. We'll help you out.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do it now.

Comment: Sorry, I have to wait 90minutes to ask a question. I edited it a few times too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file to read remains constant, you could just pass `ID` as a parameter. Everything else remains the same, except the `print` is converted to a `return`. Also, I would recommend using `with...as` to handle file I/O.

```
def SearchStudent(ID):
    with open("Students.txt", 'r') as file:
        for i in file:
            data = i.rstrip().split(",")
            if data[0] == ID:
                return "The student you require is: {} {}".format(data[2], data[1])

    return "No matches found"
```

---

```
search = input("Please enter a student ID: ")
print(SearchStudent(search))
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for helping. I ran the code and It says that it is missing one required positional argument 'ID'. I have no idea what this means

Comment: @CV9 I hope you saw the second part... `SearchStudent(search)` you need to _pass_ the actual ID to the function for it to work. Make sure you pass a string and not an integer.

Comment: Hey it is working and does bring up the name of the student based on their ID entered. However, it still gives an error of positional argument and this is the part that I don't understand. This is what I have ran: search = input("Please enter a student ID: ")
def SearchStudent(ID):
    with open("Students.txt", 'r') as file:
        for i in file:
            data = i.rstrip().split(",")
            if data[0] == ID:
                return "The student you require is: {} {}".format(data[2], data[1])
                return "No matches found"
print(SearchStudent(search))
SearchStudent()

Comment: @CV9 Just remove this line: `SearchStudent()` you are already calling it once inside the print statement. --- if a function expects one argument, how can you call it with 0 arguments?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. Sorry, functions are tricky to me. I'm still learning. I do understand what you mean though and why I needed to take it out. It does work and your help has been really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the function **rstrip()**, you should be careful that you are not unintentionally modifying the student ID.

It is a good practice to accept the data outside the function and pass it into the function. In otherwords, it would be better if you accept the student ID normally like,

`StudentId=input("Enter Student ID: ")`

Then you can pass it into the function that you create to just tally the ID and return the name and other details.

`SrcStudent(StudentId)`

To define a function use the **def** keyword.

`def function_name(parameter):
   (lines of codes)`

Something like this may be,

`def SrcStudent(ID):
   with open("Students.txt", 'r') as file:
       for f in file:
           data = f.strip().split(",")
                if (data[0] == ID):
                     print("The student you require is: {0} {0}".format(data[2], data[1]))`

Comment: Also, rstrip removes trailing newlines from the file, it has nothing to do with the student ID. Your advice is misguided.

Comment: Furthermore, `{0} {0}` is blatantly wrong. It'll pass `data[2]` to both arguments, since that is the 0th format item.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Hey. It was by no means meant to misguide anyone. Maybe the format specifier is incorrect, but I did not copy it from you. This is the normal approach. In case you find it wrong, please let me know, I shall surely remove my answer.